# PHP Sessions Lost

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm having problems with PHP sessions dropping data and redirecting back to my login page.

This is the directory structure I have from the top:

---

1. Login // Contains files to login/logout
2. Main // Contains pages for logged in users
3. index.php // Login screen with fully operational form

In login directory: check_login.php

In main directory: page1.php, folder1 and folder2

In folder 1: home.php, include1.php

In folder 2: include2.php

(Sorry if this is not very easy to understand)

---

This is the code I run when logging in on check_login.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = $id; 
header("location:../main/page1.php"); //into main directory
```

All of the pages contain the same styling (heading, navigation, footer) and have one main content block that changes per page so therefore I use includes contained in folder1 and folder2 depending on the content to be displayed. By default, home.php is included for the home page which is located in folder1. Other pages use includes such as include1.php or include2.php which could be from either folder.

At the top of page1.php:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION["id"] == '')
{
header("location:../index.php");
}
```

From page1.php, if I navigate to a page with an include that is located in folder1, this works fine. If I navigate back to the home, an include also in folder1 this works fine. Both times I can read the id variable from session.

However if I navigate to a page with an include located in folder2 I get redirected to my login page.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the problem might be that you didn't declared "session_start()" when redirecting to folder2

Comment: The includes in folder 1 which I can switch between do not have session_start(); at the top, which works fine. Neither does folder 2. However I have already tried putting session_start(); at the top of all the includes in both folders and still the same issue.

Comment: What "index.php" contains?

Comment: Index.php contains all the HTML code for the header, navigation and footer. Each link in the navigation points to Index.php with a parameter being passed in the link which then determines which include to put into the main block of content.

Comment: And the file in folder 2 contain?

Comment: Simply contains files with php outputting into the block of content in index.php

Comment: Sorry buddy, this doesn't make any sense, I can't help you...

Comment: But I do HIGHLY recommend you to work with frameworks, which can handle all those kind of crap

Answer (score 0):

You need to always include your session start. A good approach for this would be to create a header.php or bootstrap.php or similar that you can include_once at the beginning of each file that extends that relies on the session. Then your code is going to cleaner and easier to manage, in addition to working properly.

Comment: Perhaps the issue isn't in your PHP code then, and rather lies with your browser flushing sessions or your server not saving the session properly to begin with. What's your software stack look like?

Comment: Well the server must save the session correctly, as it allows me to move between includes in the same directory. 

What do you mean by software stack?

Comment: When you move to a different directory, your server may be treating that as a new host. For example, consider that apache might power 5 different websites on the same physical server, but it doesn't carry those sessions across each of those websites because that would be a huge security flaw. Therefore, each host is defined by name:

http://example.com
http://puppies.com

Apache would save sessions for those by their name. So if your software stack is Apache with PHP on Linux I can help you debug those named hosts, or if you software is nginx with php it may be a different process.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about enabling my sessions to be available in other directories then? Even if it's limited to specific ones.

It is running Apache with PHP on Linux.

Comment: What is the url you are testing on? It's usually just a matter of setting up a virtual host that is specific to your project root, and once apache points to that root with a named based url, it will treat all subdirectories as part of the same root url.

Comment: And by url, i mean what does the structure look like? I dont need to know an actual URL.. but i imagine it looks like http://example.com/myproject/directory1

Comment: How do I go about configuring a virtual host then? I have never known anyone to require doing that just to simply move directory.

I am currently working on a subdomain. So: example.domain.com

Comment: If your subdomain is not pointing to your project root, then update it (or create a new one that does) and your problem may be solved. If it is already pointing to your project root, then we're back to square one, because subdomains will usually mean a unique virtual host.

Comment: What do you mean by pointing to project root? How do I about about finding this out, and changing this if that's the case?

Comment: The project root would be where your app should "start" in terms of folder structure.. so ideally example.domain.com/index.php would point to /your-project-folder/index.php directly.. If you are going even one directory further than that in the url, then it's not pointing to your project root.

Comment: For my example.domain.com I have a folder called example in my root. 
In this is example.domain.com/index.php, /main, /login. And in these are the other folders/files such as /main/folder1, /main/folder2

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this, and cannot believe my idiocy.

In one of the includes where I was echoing a link to another page, this was wrong and in fact pointing to my login page all along. Everything is working fine now, appreciate for all the help. Typical schoolboy error.